# Cannot be installed nuget package in VS2015

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

when I try to open nuget via menu or install package via console error message "**There are no writable config files.**" shown:

```
Install-Package : There are no writable config files.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some luck deleting nuget files out of AppData and restarting VS2015.

How I did it:

1) Go to c:\Users\yourname\AppData\ in File Explorer.

2) Search for "nuget"

3) Delete anything that looks like it's transient -- in particular there should be a couple .nuget folders, but I didn't mark the locations.  Since I have ReSharper and Chocolately installed, I noticed that some hits that looked specific to those applications which I did not delete.

4) Restart Visual Studio.